# Separate output file for every url given in start_urls list of spider in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to create separate output file for every url I have set in start_urls of spider or somehow want to split ouput files start url wise.

Following is the start_urls of my spider

```
start_urls = ['http://www.dmoz.org/Arts/', 'http://www.dmoz.org/Business/', 'http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/']
```

I want to create separate output file like

Arts.xml
Business.xml
Computers.xml

I don't know exactly how to do this. I am thinking to achieve this by implementing some thing like following in spider_opened method of item pipeline class,

```
import re
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import XmlItemExporter

class CleanDataPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 0
        self.filename = ''

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        referer_url = response.request.headers.get('referer', None)
        if referer_url in spider.start_urls:
            catname = re.search(r'/(.*)$', referer_url, re.I)
            self.filename = catname.group(1)

        file = open('output/' + str(self.cnt) + '_' + self.filename + '.xml', 'w+b')
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        #file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cnt = self.cnt + 1
        self.spider_closed(spider)
        self.spider_opened(spider)
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Where I am trying to find the referer url of every scraped item within the start_urls list. If referer url is found in start_urls then file name will be created using that referer url.
But problem is how to access response object inside spider_opened() method. If I can access it there, I can create file based on that.

Any help to find a way to perform this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd implement a more explicit approach (not tested):

- configure list of possible categories in `settings.py`:

  ```
  CATEGORIES = ['Arts', 'Business', 'Computers']
  ```
- define your `start_urls` based on the setting

  ```
  start_urls = ['http://www.dmoz.org/%s' % category for category in settings.CATEGORIES]
  ```
- add `category` `Field` to the `Item` class
- in the spider's parse method set the `category` field according to the current `response.url`, e.g.:

  ```
  def parse(self, response):
       ...
       item['category'] = next(category for category in settings.CATEGORIES if category in response.url)
       ...
  ```
- in the pipeline open up exporters for all categories and choose which exporter to use based on the `item['category']`:

  ```
  def spider_opened(self, spider):
      ...
      self.exporters = {}
      for category in settings.CATEGORIES:
          file = open('output/%s.xml' % category, 'w+b')
          exporter = XmlItemExporter(file)
          exporter.start_exporting()
          self.exporters[category] = exporter

  def spider_closed(self, spider):
      for exporter in self.exporters.itervalues(): 
          exporter.finish_exporting()

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
      self.exporters[item['category']].export_item(item)
      return item
  ```

You would probably need to tweak it a bit to make it work but I hope you got the idea - store the category inside the `item` being processed. Choose a file to export to based on the item category value.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't store it in the item itself, you can't really know the staring url. The following solution should work for you:

- redefine the `make_request_from_url` to send the starting url with each `Request` you make. You can store it in `meta` attribute of your `Request`. Bypass this starting url with each following `Request`.
- as soon as you decide to pass the element to pipeline, fill in the starting url for the item from `response.meta['start_url']`

Hope it helps. Following links may be helpful:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.make_requests_from_url

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=meta#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it for my project without setting the category in item:

Pass the argument from the command line like this:

```
scrapy crawl reviews_spider -a brand_name=apple
```

Receive the argument and set to spider args in the my_spider.py

```
def __init__(self, brand_name, *args, **kwargs):
    self.brand_name = brand_name
    super(ReviewsSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # i am reading start_urls from an external file depending on the passed argument
    with open('make_urls.json') as f:
        self.start_urls = json.loads(f.read())[self.brand_name]
```

In `pipelines.py`:

```
class ReviewSummaryItemPipeline(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        # change the output file name based on argument
        self.file = open(f'reviews_summary_{spider.brand_name}.csv', 'w+b')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```