# scrapy - seperate output file per starurl

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this scrapy spider that runs well:

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class AllCategoriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'vieles'
    allowed_domains = ['examplewiki.de']
    start_urls = ['http://www.exampleregelwiki.de/index.php/categoryA.html','http://www.exampleregelwiki.de/index.php/categoryB.html','http://www.exampleregelwiki.de/index.php/categoryC.html',]

#"Titel": :

def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.css('a.ulSubMenu::attr(href)').extract() # links to den subpages
    for url in urls:
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse_details)

def parse_details(self,response):
    yield {
        "Titel": response.css("li.active.last::text").extract(),
        "Content": response.css('div.ce_text.first.last.block').extract(),
    }
```

`
with

> scrapy runspider spider.py -o dat.json
>   it saves all info to dat.json

I whould like to have a outputfile per start url categoryA.json categoryB.json and so on.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639541/how-to-run-a-scrapy-scraper-multiple-times-simultaneously-on-different-input-w) has been left unanswered, I cannot reproduce [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868784/separate-output-file-for-every-url-given-in-start-urls-list-of-spider-in-scrapy) and I am not able to learn form the [suggestions there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639541/how-to-run-a-scrapy-scraper-multiple-times-simultaneously-on-different-input-w).

How do I achive the goal of having several outputfiles, one per starturl?
I whould like to only run one command/shellscript/file to achive this.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't use real urls in code so I use my page for test.
I have to changed css selectors and I used different fields.

I save it as `csv` because it is easier to append data.
`JSON` would need to read all items from file, add new item and save all items again in the same file.

---

I create extra field `Category` to use it later as filename in pipeline

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class CategoryItem(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Date = scrapy.Field()
    # extra field use later as filename 
    Category = scrapy.Field()
```

In spider I get category from url and send to `parse_details` using `meta` in `Request`.
In `parse_details` I add `category` to `Item`.

**spiders/example.py**

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['blog.furas.pl']
    start_urls = ['http://blog.furas.pl/category/python.html','http://blog.furas.pl/category/html.html','http://blog.furas.pl/category/linux.html']

    def parse(self, response):

        # get category from url
        category = response.url.split('/')[-1][:-5]

        urls = response.css('article a::attr(href)').extract() # links to den subpages

        for url in urls:
            # skip some urls
            if ('/tag/' not in url) and ('/category/' not in url):
                url = response.urljoin(url)
                # add category (as meta) to send it to callback function
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details, meta={'category': category})

    def parse_details(self, response):

        # get category
        category = response.meta['category']

        # get only first title (or empty string '') and strip it
        title = response.css('h1.entry-title a::text').extract_first('')
        title = title.strip()

        # get only first date (or empty string '') and strip it
        date = response.css('.published::text').extract_first('')
        date = date.strip()

        yield {
            'Title': title,
            'Date': date,
            'Category': category,
        }
```

In pipeline I get `category` and use it to open file for appending and save item.

**pipelines.py**

```
import csv

class CategoryPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        # get category and use it as filename
        filename = item['Category'] + '.csv'

        # open file for appending
        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)

            # write only selected elements 
            row = [item['Title'], item['Date']]
            writer.writerow(row)

            #write all data in row
            #warning: item is dictionary so item.values() don't have to return always values in the same order
            #writer.writerow(item.values())

        return item
```

In settings I have to uncomment pipelines to activate it.

**settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'category.pipelines.CategoryPipeline': 300,
}
```

---

Full code on GitHub: [python-examples/scrapy/save-categories-in-separated-files](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/scrapy/save-categories-in-separated-files)

---

**BTW:** I think you could write in files directly in `parse_details`.

Comment: I never worked with projects, only spiders so your answer is a little over my head. How does one use parse_details?

Comment: as default `Request` gets data from page and executes `parse()` but in your code you execute `Request` to get subpabe and execute `parse_details()` (`scrapy.Request(..., callback=self.parse_details,...)`). If you didn't work with project then you could use `with open(...) ...` directly in `parse_details` and you will no need `CategoryPipeline`

Comment: do you mean I could write the file right in the parse details function?

Comment: yes, you can write files in function `parse_details` - it is your code, nobody can stop you ;)