# How to save one output file per request/URL?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy and have set up:

- Items
- ItemLoader
- ItemPipeline
- start_requests using CSV to define multiple URLs
- Custom Writer

I run the scraper simply:

`scrapy crawl scraper`

However, all output goes into one file.

I would like one output file per request/URL?

What am I missing?

Comment: You can set it up in your pipelines. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369516/3923463

Comment: Awesome! I should have thought to stray from the see standard place to write the file and move it inside the parse_item function

Comment: @Ionut-CezarCiubotariu sadly this approach will not work for me because I am processing my content in pipeline

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, but in the answer I linked there is a pipeline class that is saving the items from the same category in a single file. Isn't this what you where looking for?

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand the example clearly enough. It scrapes pages to extract links that it tags by category, title&date. Each link title&date is appended to a file in the correct category folder. I tried to modify this approach for my purpose but I ran into some problems, so I created a small bash script to loop through URLs from a file, and run the spider on each one. Not as neat a solution but it was quicker for me to get it to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrapy - seperate output file per starurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361396/scrapy-seperate-output-file-per-starurl)

Comment: @Gallaecio not really a duplicate